# Should I load a DLL in the source code or just its header file? I want to be able to build the same source on linux

Tags: c, linux, winapi, dll, sdl-2

I'm trying to figure out a way to store all my dependent libraries in a sub folder, say `/libs`, and my executable outside of this folder. From what I can tell, I need to then add this library folder into the system PATH or add some code such as `HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(".\\libs\\mydll.DLL");` into my source (correct me if I'm wrong here, I'm not very sure about this).

However, the problem is, I also would like to be able to compile the same source code on Linux, without having to modify it every time I change from one OS to another. Is this possible? How can I do that in C? If possible, can you guy show me the most standard way to do it in the industry?

I know having all my DLLs outside together with my executable will solve this problem instantly, but that's just avoiding the problem altogether and I'm interested to learn more about this topic.

For example, here I have a small C code that help me initialize some SDL2 facilities:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "SDL2\SDL.h"
#include "SDL2\SDL_messagebox.h"
#include "SDL2\SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL2\SDL_ttf.h"

#define MAX_KEYBOARD_KEYS 350
#define SCREEN_WIDTH   1280
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT  720

typedef struct {
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window *window;
    int keyboard[MAX_KEYBOARD_KEYS];
} App;


App app;

void initSDL() {

    /*
    Procedure to initiate SDL2, SDL_Image, and SDL_ttf
    Log errors and quit the program if failed.
    */

    int rendererFlags, windowFlags, imgFlags;

    rendererFlags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
    windowFlags = 0;
    imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG | IMG_INIT_JPG;

    //initiate SDL stuff. If return < 0 error occured
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to initate SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    //create a window
    app.window = SDL_CreateWindow("pong", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, windowFlags);
    if (!app.window) {
        SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_ERROR, "Failed to create window: %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    //set hint for SDL
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "linear");

    //create a renderer
    app.renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(app.window, -1, rendererFlags);
    if (!app.renderer) {
        SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_ERROR, "Failed to create renderer: %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    //init IMG
    if (IMG_Init(imgFlags) == 0) {
        SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_ERROR, "Failed to initialize SDL_Image: %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    //init TTF
    if (TTF_Init() == -1) {
        SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_ERROR, "Failed to initialize SDL_ttf: %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    } 
}

void cleanUp() {

    /*
    Procedure to quit all facilities gracefully and announce a normal exit of the program
    */

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(app.renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(app.window);
    IMG_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_LogMessage(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, SDL_LOG_PRIORITY_INFO, "Exited normally");
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    /*
    Possibly here we will have that HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(".\\libs\\mydll.DLL");
    to deal with all the DLLs I have in the libs folder
    */

    initSDL();
    atexit(cleanUp);
    exit(0);
}
```

Now fortunately this code can be compiled both on Windows (mingw32) and Linux if I so choose myself. What I'm worrying about is that, after adding Windows-specific codes, my source will lose such liberty.

Comment: On Windows you use an isolation aware manifest to handle such organisation of DLLs. That is if you absolutely must put the DLLs apart from your executable, a decision you should consider very carefully.

Comment: Another option is to use [delay loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019) for the DLLs rather than using Static Linking or explicit Dynamic Loading. And then you can call [`SetDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw) or [`AddDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) at runtime before you use the DLLs.

Comment: Thank you very much David and Remy. If possible, can you explain to me why having my DLLs apart from my executable is frowned upon?
As for delay loading, I wonder if I can do that with my toolchain (gcc)?

Comment: It just complicates life for you. Put them in the same directory as the executable and there is nothing more to do. But if you have complex dependencies then it can make sense to package them up. I personally prefer the manifest approach because it means you need no code at all to resolve dependencies. It is declarative. The loader does all the work.

Comment: @stanle as you already use SDL, it have [SDL_LoadObject](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LoadObject) (resulting in `LoadLibrary` on windows, `dlopen` on unix-like, etc.). File name may be different though (unless you really want to mislead everyone).

Comment: @kel: `SDL_LoadObject` doesn't buy you much, unless you are already delay-loading modules, or use runtime-dynamic linking. The former doesn't require you to explicitly load modules, whereas the latter is fairly tedious. It's questionable whether you want to subscribe to whatever character encoding `SDL_LoadObject` subscribes to, just to get the easy part of loading a module done.

Comment: @IInspectable it have only one use case and I stated directly it is the same thing as `LoadLibrary` on windows. Whether one might want utf8 or something else for file names is a different question. `LoadLibrary` alone without `GetProcAddress` is probably useless - which is also mirrored by `SDL_LoadFunction` (`dlsym` for non-windows).